# Xamarin.Forms.Maps map pin blincking every second on SOME android devices

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin.forms

Here is a problem, I have in my Xamarin Forms project. It's OK for iOS and WinForm, but using some of android devices cause situation, when pin refreshing all the time, so user cannot navigate the map or change zoom level. Google Maps app is working fine.

It causes on Samsung S4 and some Samsung tablets, but is's OK on moto G. It also OK on another S4 device. Most of devices are 4.4.2, moto g is 4.4.4

Comment: For the very specific device support for Xamarin, I suggest you also ask question here: http://xamarin.com/support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue, and will be fixed in the next version of Xamarin Forms.